# How to calculate a simple equation through a few functions? (DOM)

Tags: javascript, dom

Hey guys I'm making this little project, where I have to randomly generate 2 numbers and operator. Then I have to store the result of this equation in an array with 3 randomly generated numbers. Afterwards all of these results will by displayed on buttons, where the user will be able to pick by clicking on the right answer.

I got to the point where the code is working for generating the numbers and operator, but my code for getting the right result plus generating the other random three results doesn't seem to work. Does anyone have any idea how to fix it? Thank you in advance!

```
<div id="count">
            <div id="text">                  
            </div>
</div>


<script>

        window.addEventListener('load', function() {

            var rnum1 = generateRandomNumber1 ();
            var rnum2 = generateRandomNumber2 ();
            var randomOperator = generateRandomOperatorAndCorrectResult ();




    document.querySelector("#text").textContent = "How much is " + rnum1  + randomOperator  +  rnum2 + "?"; 
    });


       function generateRandomOperatorAndCorrectResult () {
            var operators = [{
                sign: "+",
                method: function(rnum1,rnum2){ return rnum1 + rnum2; } },
                {
                 sign: "*",
                 method: function(rnum1,rnum2){ return rnum1 * rnum2; } },
                 {
                 sign: "-",
                method: function(rnum1,rnum2){ return rnum1 - rnum2; }
                  }];
            var results = [];

            var selectedOperator = Math.floor(Math.random()*operators.length);
            var randomOperator = operators[selectedOperator].sign;
            var correctResult = (operators[selectedOperator].method); //til this point it works
            results.push(correctResult);
            return randomOperator;
            return results;
               }

        function generateRandomResults () {
            for(var i=0; i < 4; i++) {
                results.push((Math.floor(Math.random() * 400) + 1))}

            return results;

        }   
           function generateRandomNumber1 () {
              var rnum1 = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1);
              return rnum1;}


            function generateRandomNumber2 () {
              var rnum2 = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1);
              return rnum2;}     

</script>
```

Comment: you can not return two values with two `return` statements. the first one ends the function. for getting a compound result, you need either another array or an object.

Answer (score 1):

```
  var rnum1 = generateRandomNumber1 ();
  var rnum2 = generateRandomNumber2 ();
  //pass the random numbers to the function
  var data= generateRandomOperatorAndCorrectResult(rnum1,rnum2);
  //data=["+", [5]]
  var operator=data[0];
  var result= data[1];
```

.
.
.

```
   function generateRandomOperatorAndCorrectResult (num1, num2) {
        var operators = [{
            sign: "+",
            method: function(rnum1,rnum2){ return rnum1 + rnum2; } },
            {
             sign: "*",
             method: function(rnum1,rnum2){ return rnum1 * rnum2; } },
             {
             sign: "-",
            method: function(rnum1,rnum2){ return rnum1 - rnum2; }
              }];
        var results = [];

        var selectedOperator = 
        Math.floor(Math.random()*operators.length);
        var randomOperator = operators[selectedOperator].sign;
        var correctResult = (operators[selectedOperator].method(num1, num2)); //pass the numbers to the methods
        results.push(correctResult);

        //return multiple values
        return [randomOperator,results];
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass some arguments like this .method(5,2) .. .method(rnum1, rnum2)

Answer (score 0):

The method `generateRandomOperatorAndCorrectResult` is never calling the method.

`var correctResult = (operators[selectedOperator].method);` is assigning the method function to correctResult variable. In JavaScript functions are object. So correctResult is an object of type function. And you need to call the function after the variable assignment on that line.

You can do `correctResult(rnum1, rnum2)` or `operators[selectedOperator].method(rnum1, rnum2)`
However you don't have access to the rnum1 and rnum2 in th above call. You can make rnum1, rnum2 as global variables to do that. (Although I don't suggest that). You can pass rnum1 and rnum2 as arguments to `generateRandomOperatorAndCorrectResult`
Same goes for the `results` array in the function. You can pass that too. They will be passed as reference as arrays are passed by reference in JavaScript so anything you do in the function will be reflected outside of the local scope.

I also don't see the results created anywhere other than inside the `generateRandomOperatorAndCorrectResult` method. If you have created it in another place as a global variable, then it might exist. But from the provided code, the results variable inside each of the methods seem disconnected.